# Suggesting change for the Stack Overflow careers, Deletion of job listing

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation, stack-overflow-jobs

There is no copy of the job listing once a job is applied for after the listing is deleted.

I applied for a job and quickly there after the listing was deleted from s/o. I still received an email with what i had written but no working link to the listing remained.

This caused me two problems

I cant review the job listing before a interview with the company to help double check what they are looking for. This would be especially bad if you thought you could simply pull up the listing right before the call.

I have no proof of what i applied to ! So if the employer decided to omit important aspects of the position or simply lie about the position i have no proof of what i applied for or what i was expecting the role to be like.

I understand that employers may wish to change listings or remove them however if someone applies to a listing they should receive a copy of exactly what they applied to. AFAIK other job site send you a copy of the listing.

Emil confirmation of application from s/o:
[image: Email confirmation from application]

The link in the email brings me here:
[image: Stack site with broken link]

Comment: Are you sure? I can see every job I've applied to - some several years old. What does this link show? https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/applications

Answer (score 3):

You can see your job application history under the ["Applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/applications) tab, including jobs which are no longer listed on the site such as closed listings.